# Why does numpy.find_common_type take two separate lists?

Tags: numpy

[`numpy.find_common_type()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.find_common_type.html) takes two lists: `array_types` and `scalar_types`.  The docs say the return value is:

> the maximum of array_types ignoring scalar_types, unless the maximum of scalar_types is of a different kind ([dtype.kind](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html#numpy.dtype.kind)).

I don't really understand what this means, so I tried some examples.  Here are some which seem to contradict the above description:

```
>>> np.find_common_type(['int16', 'int32'], ['uint64'])
dtype('int32')

>>> np.find_common_type(['int32', 'int64'], ['uint32'])
dtype('int64')
```

Above, `scalar_types` has `kind="u"` (unsigned), yet it does not override `array_types` which have `kind="i"`.

So, what's the point of it taking two parameters?  Real usages I've seen in the wild just pass `[]` as the second argument anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that while the docs say "unless the maximum of scalar_types is of a different kind" what they actually mean is "unless the maximum of scalar_types is of a greater kind", where "greater" is defined in a different order than on the `dtype.kind` page.  The ordering is in the code [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/core/numerictypes.py#L925):

```
['b', 'u', 'i', 'f', 'c', 'S', 'U', 'V', 'O', 'M', 'm']
```

So `scalar_types` has an effect e.g. when it contains an int type but `array_types` contains only boolean or unsigned types.  Merely being "different" is not enough--it has to be farther to the right in the above list.